# Поиск по всей базе данных MySQL

Tags: поиск, search, mysql

Возможно ли как то задать поиск по все базе данных, всех колонок всех таблиц?

Задача просканировать базу данных на предмет `eval`.

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли реализовать такой поиск ?

Comment: хм, можно выбрать все таблицы, по каждой из таблице можно получить все столбцы, и уже дальше искать по ним :)

только это приходит на ум )

Comment: а есть запрос, который получает все столбцы в таблице ? и можно ли его использовать в связке запросов ? Типа WHERE запрос на все столбцы

Comment: делай полный дамп базы и дальше grep.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно будет учесть, что некоторые колонки допустим `varchar` другие `text` и поиск должен осуществляться разными методами, где просто по маске, где полнотекстовый поиск. Выборку всех колонок всех таблиц сделать несложно

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE table_schema = 'название базы')
```

далее `AND` и можно реализовывать алгоритм поиска подстроки 'eval'

Comment: не парился, сделал дамп базы и законтрлэфил eval и тп. К сожалению ничего не нашел

Comment: Почему к сожалению? Если есть проблема с выполнением какого-то стороннего кода, то поищите не только в базе данных но и в самих файлах, недавно так нашел в одном старом проекте несколько файлов с добавленном редиректе вначале. Советую глянуть на счет присутствия не только строки "eval", но также и "base64"

Comment: та в том то и дело: нашел 200 мб вирусни на сайте, и она как-то стабильно раз в неделю попадает. Проверил базу, на систем, экзес и тп.. пусто, фсе файлы сайта антивирусником, ручным поиском, пусто. Пароли фтп меняю каждую неделю. В картинках искал вредоносный код, тоже все пусто. Не могу понять где дырка

Comment: пиши хостерам, пусть у себя еще проверят, вполне возможно их ломают а там уже и до тебя добираются, пусть логи смотрят, кто файл вредоносных положил, когда, под каким пользователем и тд.
Так же разумеется, свой комп проверь.
И глянь на всякий случай в cron на хосте - вполне возможно что туда закинут функционал загрузки вредоносного кода раз в неделю скажем и тогда никакая смена паролей конечно уже будет неважна.

Comment: @zippp, у меня похожая задача, только не ищу вредоносный код, а обычную строку, например, АБВГД. Не подскажите, как дополнить Ваш запрос ? Я попробовал, дописать в самый конец 
and column_name like '%АБВГД%' , но мне кажется, что я ошибся

Answer (score 3):

Если не программно нужно искать то посмотри программу http://www.heidisql.com/ она умеет искать слова по всей базе